# Is there any way to remove inbuilt Window Title bar in Install4j?

Tags: java, swing, install4j

I am creating a GUI based installer for Centos7 and I need to remove the inbuilt Windows Title bar which Install4j provides and I need to add my external title bar in which I want to add button and external image file for my customization purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 8.x there is no API to customize the window decoration of the installer window.